# Asp.net Web Application Publish

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, windows-7, iis-6

I am new to asp.net and failed to publish my web application on local host.
I develop my application on D:/learning/MyWebApp/*.*;

And it works quite well.

Then I created a new folder **imct**, the location is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imct\

**File System** methond selected and Successfully published.

But I can't open my app from http://localhost/imct/

> ### > Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error  Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 16:      Line
>   17:  Line 18:      Line 19:        Line 20:
>
> Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imct\web.config    Line: 18
>
> Show Additional Configuration Errors:
>
> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imct\web.config line 22)
>
> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imct\web.config line 32)
>
> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\imct\web.config line 39)

Is there anything wrong? Appreciated for your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up that folder as an Application in IIS Manager.

Comment: By adding the folder as an application. It works well now. thanks.

Comment: And another question that may beyond the original question. If I publish the app to remote sharing host. Must I contact with the hosting company customer tech support to do this?

Comment: The directory you publish to will already be set as an application.  Their control panel should allow you to make more.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Visual Studio [Publish Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165260.aspx) (Build + [Publish Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b.aspx))